# what is driver.findelementby(By.id("")) in webelement element=driver.findelementby(By.id(""))

Tags: java, c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am novice to programming but am working on Selenium automation. 
I see that in `WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver()`, both `WebDriver` and `ChromeDriver` are classes and `ChromeDriver` is implementing `WebDriver` and hence `WebDriver` is used as a reference variable to put an object of `ChromeDriver` class.

But in what is `WebElement element=driver.findelementby(By.id("something"))`, `WebElement` is a class but on the right side, it appears to be a method, I am assuming, `FindElement` is a method in `Chromedriver` class. a reference variable is equated to a method instead of an object of a class like in the above para. how is this possible? what is this conecept called. Is there any link to the concept in the above para here?

Comment: http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/

Answer (score 3):

In an assignment expression (like `a = b`), the left-hand side (`a`) is a *variable*, the right-hand side (`b`) is an *expression*.

An expression is just something which, when evaluated, has a value of some type (or `null`). Literals like `1` are expressions, but so is `1 + 1 + 1`: this can be evaluated to a value of type `int`.

If you see `WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();`, that's technically a *variable declaration **statement***. Your analysis is roughly correct, but it's important to know that:

- You are declaring a new variable here; in order to declare a new variable, it has to be a statement (note the `;`); you could simply assign an existing variable in an expression, though:

  ```
  driver = new ChromeDriver()
  ```
- you have to read the entire `new ChromeDriver()` as the expression: it's a *class instance creation expression*, where the instance you create will be a `ChromeDriver` (not a subclass).

`WebElement element=driver.findelementby(By.id("something"));` isn't really different, it's just a different type of expression of the right-hand side: it's a method invocation expression.

- Assuming you declared `driver` as above, `findelementby` is a method in the *`WebDriver`* class, not `ChromeDriver` (although it will be present in `ChromeDriver` too, as a subclass of `WebDriver`).

Answer (score 0):

In OOP methods usually return some values of various types. Sometimes method can return nothing. In Java it is annotated as `void`.

In your example you are calling static method of class `By` called `id`. What is returned from this method will be argument for method `findeElementBy` declared in `WebDriver` interface which is implemented by `ChromeDriver`. This method declares `WebElement` as return type.

Read more about Object Oriented Programming (OOP) to familiarize yourself with this concept. You can find useful resources here for example:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/ - This is related to java.
https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J3a_OOPBasics.html - here you have more examples

Answer (score 0):

In "`WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.id("something"))`"

"*`By.id("something")`*": Locator: Locators tells Selenium which GUI elements ( say Text Box, Buttons, Check Boxes etc) its needs to operate on. So, it will find "`something`" element using "`id`".

"`findElement(By.id("something"))`": Method: Locating elements in WebDriver is done by using the "findElement(By.locator())" method.

"*`WebElement element`*": Object Declaration: Instead of using the long "driver.findElement(By.locator())" syntax every time you will access a particular element, we can instantiate a WebElement object for it. The WebElement class is contained in the "org.openqa.selenium.*" package.

**FYI**, WebDriver is a web automation framework that allows you to execute your tests against different browsers, not just Chrome or Firefox or others. WebDriver also enables you to use a programming language in creating your test scripts

Answer (score 0):

Your question is right, but your assumption is wrong. `WebDriver` and `WebElement` are not class. They are interfaces implemented by `ChromeDriver` class.

`findElement` is the method declared in `WebDriver` class which returns `WebElement` interface.

`WebDriver` and `WebElement` interfaces are implemented by `RemoteWebDriver` and `RemoteWebDriver` is further extended by `ChromeDriver`.

Hope that helps!